# Выключается ноутбук HP 250 G5 (Z2Y78ES)

Tags: ноутбук

Купил полтора года назад ноутбук HP250 G5 (Z2Y78ES).

Около 2-ух месяцев назад он начал выключаться, затем умер жесткий диск.

Я купил Kingston ssd a4 на 240gb.

Теперь все работает, но ноут при длительных работах в программах(webstorm, atom, photoshop, chrome. Что будет когда запущу GULP?) выключается, через пару секунд сам включается, иногда после такого "перезапуска" он отключается снова, и появляется черный экран, мигает CAPS LOCK 3 раза (загуглил, - ошибка памяти).

Также при зарядке от сети, пропадает зарядка, потом снова появляется.

Стоит отметить что, когда я вынимаю батарею и работаю от сети, все нормально, сеть не пропадает. Но проблема с выключением (при нагрузке? остается). Только от батареи тоже пробовал работать. Все нормально, но по прежнему выключается ..

Недавно я провел стресс-тест в аиде, на 3-4 минуте появляется троттлинг процессора, дальше ждать не стал, отменил тест. Датчики показывают что проц горяченький, и нагревается быстро даже от браузера ..

Разобрал ноут, термопаста есть, серого цвета (заводская?), она не сухая, я не думаю что проблема в термопасте ..

Я не пойму в чем может быть причина? Что вызывает троттлинг, и что послужило смерти hdd(возможно умер своей смертью)?

- Двухъядерный Intel Core i3-5005U (2.0 ГГц)
- RAM 4GB DDR3L-1600 МГц
- AMD Radeon R5 M430, 2 ГБ

**Мои предположения:**

1. Что-то(что отвечает за питание на материнской плате?) вышло из строя, и подает на компоненты завышенное напряжение?
2. Я поставил ssd, и проц не может вытягивать такие накопители, ему нужно больше оперативной памяти
3. Ноут бракованный, но год проработал

Также подумываю отправить на постгарантийный ремонт, туда где купил.

Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, готов предоставить.

Comment: HDD обычно не умирают "своей смертью" через год работы. Скажу банальную, но самую полезную вещь: обратитесь к специалистам. Угадывать, что у вас потенциально могло сломаться - это все равно что гадать на кофейной гуще. Да и пускай кто-то угадает, дальше вы все равно пойдете в сервисный центр для ремонта, почему бы сразу к ним не обратиться? :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да, так и думаю отправить на ремонт, просто не доверяю сервисным центрам, хоть и авторизованным. И думал возможно сам смогу сделать, ssd ведь новый поставил сам :D Ну и знать примерно в чем проблема, что бы не "ремонтировали" мне все подряд что бы выкачать деньги ..

Comment: Если у вас закончилась гарантия, есть смысл воспользоваться сервисными услугами **не** от магазина. Да и проведите просто диагностику, а не сразу ремонт.